# Angular RxJS Subscribe Behavior with Observer object - this in next/error callback

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I am learning angular and typescript. Need help to understand one problem I am facing with observable and event handler on stackblitz example below.

Event handler method 'toggleIfHandSet' on sidenav drawer expected to toggle when screen width is smaller otherwise its expected to do nothing, but result  is not as expected.

To see this happening, open live preview in new window with developer console on side and try to change width. Please also observe console log. Immediate call of Get after Set having different value. - If you can please help to understand this behavior.

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nxwu2v)

Update: 
I found out this behavior is due to the fact that RxJS subscribe handles observer object. while calling next method on observer object, this reference is not pointing to the observer object but object created from it so **proto** will hold original observer object...

Answer (score 0):

Update: I found out this behavior is due to the fact that RxJS subscribe handles observer object. while calling next method on observer object, this reference is not pointing to the observer object but object created from it so proto will hold original observer object...